# Sail.js - routing to methods, custom policies & PATCH method

Tags: sails.js

I have a few questions that I couldn't find answers anywhere online.

1. Does sails.js framework support HTTP PATCH method? If not - does anyone know if there is a planned feature in the future?
2. By default if I create method in a controller it is accessible with GET request is it the routes.js file where I need to specify that method is accessible only via POST or other type of methods?
3. How would you create a policy that would allow to change protected fields on entity only for specific rights having users. I.e: user that created entity can change "name", "description" fields but would not be able to change "comments" array unless user is ADMIN?
4. How would you add a custom header to "find" method which specifies how many items there are in database? I.e.: I have /api/posts/ and I do query for finding specific items {skip: 20; limit: 20} I would like to get response with those items and total count of items that would match query without SKIP and LIMIT modifiers. One thing that comes to my mind is that a policy that adds that that custom header would be a good choice but maybe there is a better one.
5. Is there any way to write a middle-ware that would be executed just before sending response to the client. I.e.: I just want to filter output JSON not to containt some values or add my own without touching the controller method.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

I can help with 2 and 5. In my own experience, here is what I have done:

2) I usually just check `req.method` in the controller. If it's not a method I want to support, I respond with a 404 page. For example:

```
    module.exports = {
        myAction: function(req, res){
            if (req.method != 'POST')
                return res.notFound();

            // Desired controller action logic here
        }
    }
```

5) I create services in api/services when I want to do this. You define functions in a service that accept callbacks as arguments so that you can then send your response from the controller after the service function finishes executing. You can access any service by the name of the file. For example, if I had MyService.js in api/services, and I needed it to work with the request body, I would add a function to it like this:

```
exports.myServiceFunction = function(requestBody, callback){
    // Work with the request body and data access here to create
    // data to give back to the controller
    callback(data);
};
```

Then, I can use this service from the controller like so:

```
    module.exports = {
        myAction: function(req, res){
            MyService.myServiceFunction(req.body, function(data){
                res.json(data);
            });
        }
    }
```

In your case, the data that the service sends back to the controller through the callback would be the filtered JSON.

I'm sorry I can't answer your other questions, but I hope this helps a bit. I'm still new to Sails.js and am constantly learning new things, so others might have better suggestions. Still, I hope I have answered two of your questions.